Apps Script Google: Generate Document based on Cell Value Utilizing different Google Doc Templates
Absolute noob here so pardon me... I don't even know if I can explain what I am looking for
I utilize two different Google Doc files as Letter Templates and would like my script to choose the appropriate template based on cell value.
I am able to utilize one of these templates successfully but am unsure how/where to add the code to have it choose a different template file depending on cell value.
Both templates utilize the same information found in the spreadsheet but the surrounding body text is different.
This is my current code:
function onOpen() {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  sheets.forEach
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const menu = ui.createMenu('AutoFill Docs');
  menu.addItem('Create New Docs', 'createNewDocument');
  menu.addToUi();

}

function createNewDocument() {

  const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('REDACTED');
  const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('REDACTED');
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Currently Processing');
  const rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  rows.forEach(function(row,index){
    if(index === 0) return;
    if(row[30]) return;
    if(!row[3]) return;
    var fullName = row[3];
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(row[0]), "PST", "MMMM dd, yyyy");
    var bothNames = fullName.split(" ");
    var firstName = bothNames[0];
    var lastName = bothNames[1];
    var abbreviatedName = firstName.substring(0, 1) + ". " + lastName;

    var fileName = abbreviatedName + ", " + date + " ESA Housing Letter";
    
    const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy(fileName, destinationFolder);
    
    const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());
    const body = doc.getBody();

    body.replaceText(`{{Name}}`, row[3]);
    body.replaceText(`{{state}}`, row[6]);
    body.replaceText(`{{one/two}}`, row[10]);
    body.replaceText(`{{animalname1}}`, row[11]);
    body.replaceText(`{{animalbreed1}}`, row[12]);
    body.replaceText(`{{age1}}`, row[13]);
    body.replaceText(`{{weight1}}`, row[14]);
    body.replaceText(`{{chartnote1}}`, row[15]);
    body.replaceText(`{{animalname2}}`, row[16]);
    body.replaceText(`{{animalbreed2}}`, row[17]);
    body.replaceText(`{{age2}}`, row[18]);
    body.replaceText(`{{weight2}}`, row[19]);
    body.replaceText(`{{chartnote2}}`, row[20]);
    body.replaceText(`{{fullstate}}`, row[23]);
    body.replaceText(`{{title}}`, row[24]);
    body.replaceText(`{{fulltitle}}`, row[25]);
    body.replaceText(`{{licensenumber}}`, row[26]);
    body.replaceText(`{{fulladdress}}`, row[27]);
    body.replaceText(`{{her/him}}`, row[28]);
    body.replaceText(`{{her/his}}`, row[29]);
    body.replaceText(`{{grammatics}}`, row[31]);
    body.replaceText(`{{grammatical count}}`, row[32]);
    body.replaceText(`{{animalXs}}`, row[33]);
    body.replaceText(`{{ASx}}`, row[34]);
    body.replaceText(`{{havehas}}`, row[31]);
    body.replaceText(`{{XXX}}`, Utilities.formatDate(new Date(row[4]), "PST", "MMMM dd, yyyy"));
    body.replaceText(`{{DOS}}`, Utilities.formatDate(new Date(row[0]), "PST", "MMMM dd, yyyy"));

    const url = doc.getUrl();
    sheet.getRange(index + 1, 31).setValue(url);

  })





}


I don't use templates but I think you could have multiple template files and use file.makeCopy() from DriveApp and then  open up the copies by id with google docs and use them for the files.

How about this:
function createNewDocument() {
  rows.forEach(function (row, index, templateid) {
    const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('templateid');
    const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1k6dPK2m6hJ7HlXMM4BLISEspoVJLQPyT');
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Currently Processing');
    const rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    if (index === 0) return;
    if (row[30]) return;
    if (!row[3]) return;
    var fullName = row[3];
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(row[0]), "PST", "MMMM dd, yyyy");
    var bothNames = fullName.split(" ");
    var firstName = bothNames[0];
    var lastName = bothNames[1];
    var abbreviatedName = firstName.substring(0, 1) + ". " + lastName;
    var fileName = abbreviatedName + ", " + date + " ESA Housing Letter";
    const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy(fileName, destinationFolder);
    const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());
    const body = doc.getBody();
    body.replaceText(`{{Name}}`, row[3]);
    body.replaceText(`{{state}}`, row[6]);
    body.replaceText(`{{one/two}}`, row[10]);
    body.replaceText(`{{animalname1}}`, row[11]);
    body.replaceText(`{{animalbreed1}}`, row[12]);
    body.replaceText(`{{age1}}`, row[13]);
    body.replaceText(`{{weight1}}`, row[14]);
    body.replaceText(`{{chartnote1}}`, row[15]);
    body.replaceText(`{{animalname2}}`, row[16]);
    body.replaceText(`{{animalbreed2}}`, row[17]);
    body.replaceText(`{{age2}}`, row[18]);
    body.replaceText(`{{weight2}}`, row[19]);
    body.replaceText(`{{chartnote2}}`, row[20]);
    body.replaceText(`{{fullstate}}`, row[23]);
    body.replaceText(`{{title}}`, row[24]);
    body.replaceText(`{{fulltitle}}`, row[25]);
    body.replaceText(`{{licensenumber}}`, row[26]);
    body.replaceText(`{{fulladdress}}`, row[27]);
    body.replaceText(`{{her/him}}`, row[28]);
    body.replaceText(`{{her/his}}`, row[29]);
    body.replaceText(`{{grammatics}}`, row[31]);
    body.replaceText(`{{grammatical count}}`, row[32]);
    body.replaceText(`{{animalXs}}`, row[33]);
    body.replaceText(`{{ASx}}`, row[34]);
    body.replaceText(`{{havehas}}`, row[31]);
    body.replaceText(`{{XXX}}`, Utilities.formatDate(new Date(row[4]), "PST", "MMMM dd, yyyy"));
    body.replaceText(`{{DOS}}`, Utilities.formatDate(new Date(row[0]), "PST", "MMMM dd, yyyy"));
    const url = doc.getUrl();
    sheet.getRange(index + 1, 31).setValue(url);
  })
}


I see where you changed things up and added in the "Template ID" - so here, I would put in the two file ID numbers for my templates correct? And then I would need to add in an 'if' rule to have it choose that specific template based on the cell value?

There are lots  of ways to go.  It all depends upon what you want

Whats the best way to teach myself what I want? Is there a Coding Lingo for Dummies somewhere? I have been fine tuning this thing for about a year because it takes me awhile to figure out the correct language. I can get Google to populate an answer similar enough to what I am looking for that I can tweak it for the result I want but I have a few more things I'd like it to do.
I want to understand the answer, not just fill in the blanks ya know

I've read  several  books on Javascript and I refer to the online documentation regularly,  I learn from looking at the examples of other volunteers here on SO and figure what they are doing by studying the online documenation .  for my own work I take my best shot and then as a use it ideas may come and I may change things.
